# combine 2 tables in 1 row using join and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have two tables = debitur and resume. I want to combine 2 tables in 1 row like this

What is the query?

```
SELECT lao, SUM(outstanding) as Outstanding, COUNT(lao) as jumlah
FROM debitur
GROUP BY lao
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(tgt_pergeseran) as Target
FROM resume
GROUP BY lao
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide more information like the primary keys of the tables so we can help you in the best way possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This-

```
SELECT 
A.lao,
A.Outstanding,
A.jumla,
B.Target 
FROM
(
    SELECT lao, 
    SUM(outstanding) as Outstanding, 
    COUNT(lao) as jumlah 
    FROM debitur 
    GROUP BY lao
 )A
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
    lao,
    SUM(tgt_pergeseran) as Target 
    FROM resume 
    GROUP BY lao
) B
ON A.lao = B.lao
```

Comment: you missed  lao in second subquery

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join between the two queries based on lao, but for this you need lao is subquery select too

```
select 
    t1.lao, t1.Outstanding, t1.jumlah, t2.Target
from
    (select
         lao, sum(outstanding) as Outstanding, count(lao) as jumlah
     from
         debitur 
     group by
         lao)
inner join
    (select
         lao, sum(tgt_pergeseran) as Target 
     from
         resume 
     group by 
         lao) t2 on t2.lao = t1.lao
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support `full join`.  So, if you want all the records in both tables -- even when some are missing -- then I recommend `union all`/`group by`:

```
SELECT lao, SUM(outstanding) as Outstanding,
       COUNT(outstanding) as jumlah,
       SUM(target) as target
FROM ((SELECT d.loa, d.outstanding, null as target
       FROM debitur d
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT r.loa, NULL, r.tgt_pergeseran as target
       FROM resume r
      ) 
     ) rd
GROUP BY lao ;
```